# Custom permission evaluating to null

Tags: null, custom-permission

I would like your help to understand what I'm missing.

I am evaluating a custom permission in a formula to check wether the user has the permission set assigned, here is the formula:

```
AND(
    NOT($User.BypassValidationRules__c),
    NOT($Setup.VRConfiguration__c.Bypass_Update_Stage_on_Closed_Won__c),
    RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Apprentissage',
    ISPICKVAL(Stage__c, 'Activated - Closed Won'),
    ISCHANGED(Contract_Type__c),
    NOT($Permission.FinAdmin == TRUE) --> this is returning null in the console values
)
```

as you can see the custom permission is returning null, here is the console view:

`11:02:31:000 VALIDATION_FORMULA )|$User.BypassValidationRules__c=0 , RecordType.DeveloperName=Apprentissage , Contract_Type__c=Contrat d'apprentissage , $Permission.FinAdmin=null , $Setup.VRConfiguration__c.Bypass_Update_Stage_on_Closed_Won__c=null , Stage__c=Activated - Closed Won`

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you double checked that the custom permission was added to the permission set and the user you tested with for the debug log has that permission set?

Comment: are you sure you are not confusing the  permission set with the custom permission? Custom Permissions are booleans. They are components in a permission set. The permission set is assigned to users. permission sets and custom permissions need not have have same names

Comment: hi @KrisGoncalves, yes I added it to the permission set which the user has but still null

Comment: @cropredy I didn't know they need to have the same name?? If I remember correctly it is not necessary as long as you add the custom permission to the permission set. I will test renaming and let you know thanks

Comment: you misread my comment - permission sets and custom permission do not need to have the same name

Comment: ah ok, but then they still giving me null for the evaluation, I created the custom permission, I added it to the permission set and as you see the evaluation returns null... it is my first time seeing this

Comment: In your permission set, look for checkbox which says "Session Activation Required", if it is "checked" the unchecked it, then run the scenario you're suppose to run and check the validation its working or not

Comment: @Amitkumar it is the same, Salesforce didn't provide any help anyways, and it has been a year since this issue, I went for custom code verification, which is sad to go that way